# X | undefined narrows to never without checking arrow function

Tags: typescript

The following code produces an error in TypeScript when `strictNullChecks` is enabled:

```
function foo(cb) {
  cb()
}

let h: { a: number } | undefined = undefined // required to reproduce this bug
foo(() => h = { a: 1 })
if (h) {
  console.log(h.a) // <-- h is of type `never`
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(cb)%20%7B%0A%20%20cb()%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20h%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%20%7C%20undefined%20%3D%20undefined%20%2F%2F%20required%20to%20reproduce%20this%20bug%0Afoo(()%20%3D%3E%20h%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D)%0Aif%20(h)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(h.a)%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20h%20is%20of%20type%20%60never%60%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript control flow analysis.

references:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28038

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998